# setting environment to preprod or prod for curity

Tags: curity

we are using Curity 6.5.3 version and creating a custom plugin to deploy. AFter the deployment, the services do not start.
we want to set the standard environment to preprod or prod for curity.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you're talking about the [Signicat Plugin](https://github.com/curityio/signicat-authenticator).

I've installed that in Curity, and here's how I configured the environment setting in the `idsh` CLI:

```
▶ dist/bin/idsh

User renatoathaydes last logged in 2022-07-13T14:21:29.376931+00:00, to Renatos-MBP-2, from 127.0.0.1 using cli-console
renatoathaydes connected from 127.0.0.1 using console on Renatos-MBP-2
renatoathaydes@Renatos-MBP-2> configure 
Entering configuration mode private
[ok][2022-07-13 16:27:08]

[edit]
renatoathaydes@Renatos-MBP-2% edit profiles profile authentication 
Possible completions:
  user-management-service  oauth-service  authentication-service
renatoathaydes@Renatos-MBP-2% edit profiles profile authentication authentication-service settings authentication-service authenticators     
[ok][2022-07-13 16:27:29]

[edit profiles profile authentication authentication-service settings authentication-service authenticators]
renatoathaydes@Renatos-MBP-2% set authenticator my-signicat signicat env
                                                                     ^
% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.
renatoathaydes@Renatos-MBP-2% set authenticator my-signicat signicat standard-environment pr
Possible completions:
  pre-production - Non-production environment for testing and verification
  production     - The production environment should be use
renatoathaydes@Renatos-MBP-2% set authenticator my-signicat signicat standard-environment production 
[ok][2022-07-13 16:27:54]

[edit profiles profile authentication authentication-service settings authentication-service authenticators]
```

Notice that the CLI supports auto-completion when you hit TAB. Should be easy to figure out how to set the other settings that are required.